# ¿Como obtener el valor de un atributo en especifico de un objeto que esta en un array? javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Hola quiero acceder al valor cargado que tiene un atributo (sea nombre, apellido o edad) de un objeto, lo estuve intentando de una forma que no funciona:

```js
define([], function(){

//clase persona
return class Persona{

    constructor(nombre, apellido, edad){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellido=apellido;
        this.edad=edad;
    }


    set setNombre(nuevoValor){
        this.nombre=nuevoValor;
    }

    set setApellido(nuevoValor){
        this.apellido=nuevoValor;
    }

    set setEdad(nuevoValor){
        this.edad=nuevoValor;
    }

    get getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    get getApellido(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    get getEdad(){
        return this.nombre;
    }



    
}  

  })
  
  
  define(['jquery','persona'],function($,p){

  //creacion de objetos y guardo cada uno en un array
    const luz = new p('Luz', 'Perez' , 20);
    const camila = new p('Camila', 'Gomez' ,21);
    const lucio = new p('Lucio', 'Fernandez', 22);
    const carlos = new p('Carlos', 'Gonzalez', 23);

    /*console.log(luz);
    console.log(camila);
    console.log(lucio);
    console.log(carlos);*/

    const listaPersonas=[luz, camila , lucio , carlos];

    return{

      lista:listaPersonas

    }  


})
require(['jquery','index'], 


    function($,i) {

         //aca es donde estoy llamando a la lista y al atributo del objeto
        console.log(i.lista.luz)
        console.log(i.lista.luz.getNombre)
        console.log(i.lista.lucio.getEdad)
    

})
```

Comment: define no es una funcion en javascript, y la forma en la que estas importando las cosas tampoco, estas confundiendo al parecer `nodeJS` con `javascript` o `PHP` con `javascript`.

Comment: NodeJS es Javascript. En cualquier caso está usando algúna librería extra

Comment: estoy usando require por que tengo muchos script en el html , ya encontré la solución, cree una variable personaEdad = i.lista[0] (y le asigne la lista y puse la posición del objeto que quiero obtener el atributo) , después llame a esa variable y le puse el get del atributo que quería , así: personaEdad.getEdad !

Comment: @PabloLozano es cierto, pero me refiero a que el usuario no coloco como etiqueta `nodejs` si el esta usando javascript puro `require` no sera reconocido, y aunque fuese reconocido creo que la sintaxis usada por el usuario es incorrecta?, jamas habia visto un `require` hecho de esa forma...

Comment: @Riven oh eso no sabia, pensé que no era necesario lo de nodejs , solo descargue la librería de requireJS lo loco es q me funciona :I , gracias voy a tener en cuenta eso

Comment: @computer Ahh!!, entonces te falto tambien colocar que estas usando requireJS xd, enrealidad creo que el hecho del porque te funciona es por `requireJS` en cuyo caso `NO` necesitas usar `nodejs` ya que la funcion `require` viene construida en `requireJS`, es por este tipo de motivos que es necesario colocar este tipo de informacion relevante en la pregunta, si no tendremos mal entendidos como este xd.